# javascript and react call async action on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class which calls some async actions in `ComponentDidMount`

It is like :

```
componentDidMount(){
// var my_call = new APICall()
Promise.resolve(new APICall()).then(console.log(FB))
}

class APICall{
    constructor(){
        window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : '254258789655',
                    cookie     : true, 
                    xfbml      : true, 
                    version    : 'v2.5'
                });

            }
        if (typeof(FB) == 'undefined') {
            ((d, s, id) => {
              let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s);
              js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
        }
    }
}

export default APICall
```

Here but my call is not synchronous.

How can I call the value of `then` only after my `api` class has been called.

Here it is giving me `FB` is not defined error. How can I first load `sdk` and then call `FB`

Thank you

Comment: That depends on what `APICall` actually does/  You should make it return a promise.

Comment: @Alexander can you please look at my updates and give me idea ??

Comment: What on earth is `FB`? Where is this variable defined? What is `sdk`? You are not providing a clear picture at all, and it seems you are really lost on scopes and execution contexts. Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

[`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes a function *reference*, while you've given it the return result of [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log), which is [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

The side effect is that `console.log` was invoked, and `"hellooww"` was printed.

You need to provide a new execution context, also known as a callback.

```
componentDidMount () {
  Promise.resolve(new APICall()).then(function () {
    console.log("hellooww");
  });
}
```

Comment: I have editeed my question. Can you please help with that ?

Comment: My current answer is still applicable to your code. Please read about `.then`'s function signature, and realize that `.then(console.log(...))` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I have added `.then(function(){console.log(FB)})` but its giving me FB is not defined error. That means `console.log(FB)` is called first before my `APICall()` class

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Promise.resolve` you are returning a resolved promise, so the `then` gets executed immediately.
You probably want your `then` code to execute when `fbAsyncInit` is called, so you need to build some mechanism that will connect your component to that flow.